# Perl splitting with leading and trailing delimiters

Tags: perl

This is my first post in this forum. I am facing a problem in splitting the below string.

String in a File with leading space, multiple spaces in between and pipe symbol:

```
$str= | U-mom  |   9.2 |   2.30E-04 | 9.60E-04 |    1.04E-04  OK |;
```

I could not place multiple spaces in my string shown above, but there are multiple spaces after `"U-mom"`

1. I have tried splitting it using: `$str = join "", split ' ', $str;`

   Result: `|U-mom|9.2|2.30E-4|9.60E-4|1.04E-04OK|`
2. Next I have used: `split(/\|/,$str);`
   stored each string in array and the result is:

---

```
0      
U-mom0  
9.20  
2.30E-040  
9.60E-040  
1.04E-04OK0
```

The result outputs 0 as starting array and 0 comes as suffix in every element of array.
Require help to overcome this problem.

Comment: can you post the code you are using to print `$str`?

Comment: The code you are showing does not add zeros `0` to the end of elements in arrays. You are not showing the part of your code that is important, so this question cannot be answered (except possibly by guessing).

Comment: $m=0;                                                               my @values = split(/\|/,$str);                                   foreach my $val (@values) {  
  $m++;  
       $fname[$m] = $val;  
       printf (OFH "%s\n",$val); #output to file  
       }

Comment: Sorry guys, As mattexx and TLP pointed out, I found out the problem, it was as a simple mistake of printing. I used printf(OFH,"%s%d\n",$val). I have added extra %d by mistake, which was resulting in 0's.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `split`'s first parameter is a regular expression and not a string. (Or, it should be a regular expression). You can do something like this:

```
my @values = split /\s+\|\s+/, "$string";
```

Note that this will make `$values[0]` a null string since there's a `|` with blank spaces at the beginning of your string. If those blank spaces aren't there, `$values[0]` would be `| U-mom`. Also note that the last entry will end with `|` since there are no blank spaces after the last `|`. if there were spaces, your last entry would actually be correct.

One way to get around this is to purposefully put spaces before and after your string:

```
my @values = split /\s+\|\s+/, "  $string  ";
splice (@values, 0, 1);  # Removes that first blank entry;
```

Now, we can print it out:

```
for my $entry (@values) {
    say "$entry";
}
```

Or...

```
for my $index (0..$#values) {
    say "Index: $index   Entry: '$values[$index]'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The split function accepts a regular expression. If you know that there are going to be leading and trailing spaces, just build that into your regular expression to split on.

```
my $str = "| U-mom | 9.2 | 2.30E-04 | 9.60E-04 | 1.04E-04 OK |";
print "$_\n" for split(/\s*\|\s*/, $str);
# output: 
# U-mom
# 9.2
# 2.30E-04
# 9.60E-04
# 1.04E-04 OK
```

`\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters

Comment: Why would you use `(?:\s+)?` instead of just `\s*` ?

Comment: Also, the `?` by itself, as used here, is not a "greedy" operator of any sort. When placed after a quantifier like `+` it becomes the *non*-greedy operator, because those quantifiers are greedy by default.  (The other use is after the `(`, when it signals a special operation, in this case just simple grouping without capture).

Comment: @MarkReed a good question, and I am going to blame lack of coffee. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You should not use `map` as a loop iterator -- use `for`, that's what its for.

Comment: The important piece is the split, not the map. That is just how I decided to display the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your second try should work, except that is is not catching the spaces:

```
perl -e 'print join("\n",split(/\s+\|\s+/," | U-mom | 9.2 | 2.30E-04 | 9.60E-04 | 1.04E-04"))'

U-mom
9.2
2.30E-04
9.60E-04
1.04E-04
```